# Reset an AD trust password without domain admin rights at both ends

Tags: active-directory

I have two domains in different forests with an external, two way domain trust in a wndows 2003 level active directory environment.  Logins from the remote domain are not working correctly, and when validating the AD trust I get the following error:

---

*The secure channel (SC) reset on Active Directory Domain Controller \MyAD01.mydomain.local of domain mydomain.local to domain remotedomain.Local failed with error: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.*

*Resetting the trust passwords might solve the problem.*

---

Resetting the trust passwords through this dialogue requires knowing the domain credentials for a domain administrator account in the remote domain.

Assuming that neither side has domain admin access to the other domain is there any way to reset the trust password, such as both sides entering an identical new password to use (similar to the way the trust was originally set up with both sides using the same initial password)

Creating a new account with domain admin rights and giving the login details to the other domain would allow a reset, but that may stall due to internal politics so if this can be done another way that would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well admins of both domains could sit next to one another during this operation and pretty pony promise to look the other way while the other one is typing in their domain's credentials.